# Retrieving date from sequence does not give the value

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following code in **R**

```
> mySeq <-  seq(as.Date("2012-1-1",format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
          as.Date("2012-1-3",format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
          by="1 day")

> for (i in mySeq){print(i)}
```

And I get:

```
[1] 15340
[1] 15341
[1] 15342
```

but `mySeq[1]` returns `"2012-01-01"`

Why? what am I missing here?

Comment: if you add `as.Date(i)` will give you what you want. `for (i in mySeq){print(as.Date(i))}`

Comment: Actually your solution did not work for me. I get: <code>for (i in mySeq){print(as.Date(i))}</code>
Error in as.Date.numeric(i) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date values are converted to numeric in `for()` function to use them as index values.

Instead you can use `seq_along()` to get index values and then print `mySeq[i]`.

```
for(i in seq_along(mySeq)) {print(mySeq[i])}
```

Comment: +1 I was already putting this down as an answer, but you where faster :)

Comment: @PaulHiemstra it doesn't happen too often, usually I'm the one who have to discard my answer as it is already answered.

Comment: +1 for identifying the coercion to numeric.

Comment: Alternatively, use `for (i in as.list(mySeq)) {print(i)}`.  If you'll need `i` more than once in the body of the `for` loop, this is easier than typing `mySeq[i]` every time.